# order rows based on some sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table like this

```
ID   Subject       StatusCd     Date
------------------------------------------
1    abc           3            01/03/2013
2    def           1            01/03/2013
3    ghi           2            05/03/2013
4    jkl           3            02/03/2013
5    mno           3            06/03/2013
```

How can I write a SQL query which will order rows in this sequence of `StatusCd` (3, 1, 2).
Also I want to sort each row in a group based on its `Date`.

Comment: thanks techdo, i was figuring out how to do it.

Comment: In the formatting header, place the code part inside `{}` to highlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression the the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select id, subject, statuscd, date
from yt
order by 
  case statuscd
    when 3 then 0
    when 1 then 1
    when 2 then 2
  end, date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a94e5/2). This gives a result:

```
| ID | SUBJECT | STATUSCD |       DATE |
----------------------------------------
|  1 |     abc |        3 | 2013-01-03 |
|  4 |     jkl |        3 | 2013-02-03 |
|  5 |     mno |        3 | 2013-06-03 |
|  2 |     def |        1 | 2013-01-03 |
|  3 |     ghi |        2 | 2013-05-03 |
```

Comment: Can we add where clause to the above statement ?

Comment: @SujithKp Yes, you can put a where clause before the order by.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select 
    ID, 
    [Subject], 
    StatusCd, 
    [Date] 
from
    YourTable
order by case StatusCd when 3 then 0 else StatusCd end, 
    [date]
```